# 2 classes of css with same name and call them individually

Tags: html, css

I have 2 class of same name

```
.class{ ...}
.class{ ...}
```

I want to call both classes simultaneously.

```
<p class="class">first class</p>  
<p class="class">second class</p>
```

Some help.

Comment: Why two same class what you want to achieve.

Comment: Why would you do the first one? First declaration/definition targets every `p` of that class name.

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_syntax.asp

Comment: always take a class Name is different, otherwise create a ambiguous.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23199413/css-rule-for-two-class-names-provided-in-spaces-for-the-class-attribute

Comment: What does "call both class names simultaneously" mean? What is your desired output?

Comment: Call for what? Call in what?

Comment: Its the right time for you to land [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9432481/declaring-same-css-class-multiple-time) and [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/selector.html#class-html)

Comment: Once a CSS class declared then the class can be assigned to multiple HTML elements.  Your current code will work without any problem. Just remove the duplicate `.class` declaration in your stylesheet.

Comment: you can't use same class name for 2 times, so instead of making 2 different classes of same name just make a single class and get it wherever you want.

Comment: I have 2 css files and they got a class with the same name, at a certain element i want to use the class from one css file and at another element I want to use class of another css file, All i want to know is if its possible and if yes, then how.

Comment: I gather from your comments that you can't change the CSS and you can't change the HTML, right? Then there's not much you can do. JavaScript?

Comment: i can try Javascript and i can change the html too,got anything?

Comment: and also no inline styling @Mr Lister

Answer (score 1):

Check this example:

- `.class` select all
- `.class:first-child` select only the first
- `.class:last-child` select only the last
- `.class:last-child` select only the specified position

edited: I've added inline style to modify the single element without modify css file (as your request in comment)

```css
.class{
  color:red;
}

.class:first-child {
  background: yellow;
}

.class:last-child  {
  background: green;
}

.class:nth-child(2n) {
  background: purple;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <p class="class">first class</p>  
  <p class="class">second class</p>
  <p class="class">last class</p>  
</div>


<div class="wrapper-inline">
  <p style="color:red">first class</p>  
  <p style="color:green">second class</p>
  <p style="color:blue">last class</p>  
</div>
```

Comment: Nice @red, but I want to do this without selector, I cannot alter the css file, is there a way?

Comment: see the inline versione of style in my edited answer

Comment: No, I have the class i just want to consume it, inline styling is not an option. Well, i shall take it as there is no way to use the class as I want, is there?

Comment: no sorry, the only way is to use different class name